# TFS 2018 (on-prem) unable to load static content

Tags: tfs-2018

Using Chrome or MS EDGE we notice some resources are not being loaded when various pages on TFS are requested by browser such as seen below:
[image: EDGE dev tools showing failed download of resources]

**Impact of this:**
We notice missing icons on the UI most often like this:
[image: showing missing icrons]

Our version of TFS

[image: version of TFS 2018]

We have seen this post and tried to reach out to the contact for the hotfix, however have not had a response back.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/338655/tfs-2018-update-3-attempting-to-load-from-static2s.html

Any assistance for this issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Found a post on the internet (I can't find the link now) that we implemented.

i.e. Add the TFS service account the Group Policy rights for "Impersonate a client after authentication" (seen under Local policies > User Rights Assignment)

A restart of the server or services is required, afterward.